# DB Design - parent child category mapping

Tags: database, database-design

I have the following categories:

Fruits
Vegetables
Cars
Bikes

For each category, we can have common sub category or different sub category like

1) Colors would be available for fruits, vegetables, cars and bikes
2) Engine would be available for cars and bikes
3) Weight would be available for fruits, vegetables, cars and bikes
4) Edible would be available for fruits and vegetables

I am thinking about the following structure:

```
category_id
category_name
parent_id
```

But using above table, I need to replicate engine category twice, weight 4 times and so on.

Is there a better way of managing parent-child relationship in the table?

Comment: I don't think those are subcategories, more like attributes?

Comment: @JuhaK I have options like red, green as categories.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your categories are supposed to be here. Surely you could have 4 tables: Fruit, Vegetable, Car, and Bike, and in those tables you'd have columns for colour, engine, weight, edible and so on, as needed?

Answer (score -1):

No need to create sub category table for the colors, weight and edible.

Because color is item dimension and weight is unit. you can have additional fields in the item tables to handle this. Ex: tblCars, tblBikes, tblFruitsAndVegs.

And Edible is enum. you can add this field in Category table itself.